# Fitting two different mixture distributions

Tags: r, mixture-distribution, lognormal-distribution, power-law

is there a package in R to fit two different mixture distributions in R ? Let's say I want to fit a mixture of power law distribution and lognormal distribution. Is this possible ? I know you can fit the mixture of two normal distributions or two poisson distributions with mixtools package in R, but what if I need to fit two different parametric mixture models ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the flexmix package. You can see in the page 9 of the vignette here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexmix/vignettes/flexmix-intro.pdf.

If you wanted, for example, a mixture of a poisson and a normal distribution, you'd want something like:

```
example <- flexmix(y~1, data=dat, k=2,
        model=list(FLXMRglm( ~ x, family ="gaussian"), 
                FLXMRglm( ~ x, family="poisson")))
```

Comment: The answer by M.D. is not correct, the R code is fitting a mixture of two Gaussians for y, and then also a mixture of two Poissons for y. The resulting models are two mixture models actually, just fitted in one function call. This can be check with example@components